# ASP.NET MVC 4 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor

I have an asp.net mvc 4 project working on VS2010, it was working fine yesterday but I uninstalled VS2012 and the project has now stopped working, it throws the following exception message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked and this is not referenced anywhere in the project, the project uses SignalR, maybe this is a requirement for it?
I have checked the related questions in the site but still cannot make it work

Web.config file under Views folder:

```
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: check the `web.config` file stored in the `Views` folder. There should be an entry for this assembly. Make sure to remove that only if it is not present in the referenced assemblies

Comment: it seems your MVC version has been updated. I also faced the same issue. check the version of your System.Web.Mvc

Comment: There's no razor referenced in my web.config in the Views folder, this is how the file looks like:

Comment: make sure "Copy Local" is set to "True" in the properties of the .dll.

Comment: I don't have that dll referenced anywhere

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I've searched the entire solution for ANY instance of 2.0.0.x and found NOTHING! There's not one single reference to ANY assembly with a 2 in it anywhere in my solution let alone System.Web.WebPages.Razor. 
  
I've checked the actual version number of all the assemblies from the System.Web.WebPages namespace and they're all 3.0. 
  
1. Uninstalled the MVC package from Nuget and reinstalled it. 
  
2. Removed the assemblyBinding elements from Web.config. 
  
3. Cleaned/rebuilt the solution. 4. Unloaded the sol and looked through the .proj file for any references.

Comment: In my case I installed back VS2012 and it worked again